# Shopping cart Asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a aspx page and inside I have called a .ascx page which is the shopping cart , on the aspx page I have a lot of links to the books and we can add the books to the shopping cart. On clicking the add button i store the bookid,name,price in a cookie and on the ascx page i get the copy and paste the value in the shopping cart using session variable everything is working fine..The code is something like this..on clicking the add btn i call this javascript function

```
       function addCookies(typeShopping,id,name,price) {

       document.cookie = typeShopping + "=" + id + "," + name + "," + price;
       }
```

But after this I have to do post back so the ascx page loads and adds this info to the shopping cart. so on the btn which call this function is like this..

```
      <a onclick="addCookies('ShoppingCart',1, 'A summary of the Creed....' ,25);"href=".../ShowBooks.aspx?CategoryName=Qur'an&Mushaf&CatID=1" </a>
```

but this as you see cause the page to post back and although the item adds to the shopping cart I move to the top, how can I do that I just click and the item add and the page don't post back and I stay on the same book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `return false;` from the `onclick` handler to prevent the browser from following the default action.

Comment: i am sorry i am not good with java script , should i just do this
function  addCookies(typeShopping,id,name,price) {

document.cookie = typeShopping + "=" + id + "," + name + "," + price;
          // aspnetForm.reset();
           alert("check now");
           
            return false;
        }
Because its not working the page stills post back

Comment: No.  You need to `return` in the `onclick=""`, and you need to learn Javascript.

Comment: yup its working good but now the ascx page does not load :( any suggestion , is there any way that after this function execution i call the ascx page to load ,that will solve everything

Comment: You just asked for it to not load.  You got what you asked for.  You also need to learn about AJAX.

Comment: no no , i want it to load but without the postback any way for doing that

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to tell the addCookies method to `return false;` after performing the necessary operations. This will stop the link from actioning.

```
function addCookies(typeShopping,id,name,price) {
       document.cookie = typeShopping + "=" + id + "," + name + "," + price;
       return false;
       }
```

Comment: i did this but still after it it postback and the page refresh and i get on the top again

Comment: as @SLaks points out in his answer, you'll need to put the retun false inside the onclick attribute value.