# How to load .ascx control in .aspx page with out postback or reloading the page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have some code that is running fine , what i want is when i create a cookie i want the .ascx control to load to perform some function on the cookie but i don't want the page to post back, how can i achieve that.

Comment: So when a user adds something to his shopping cart [(per your last question)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253082/shopping-cart-asp-net) you want to update the contents of the shopping cart control?

Comment: yes but without the post back

Comment: You mean a full postback or without any kind of contact with the server?

Comment: hmmm its like this when i want to add item to cart i create a cookie but without post back i cannot load the .ascx page to add the cookie to shopping cart ,this solves the problem but as post back occurs i move to the top of the page , i want that when i add item in the shopping cart the post back do not occur and i stay at the same spot else i have to scroll down every time to go down and add item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i found a more simpler way how to just load the .ascx control without postback

Just put the .ascx control in a update panel and reload the update panel only using this..

```
   function  addCookies(typeShopping,id,name,price) {

       document.cookie = typeShopping + "=" + id + "," + name + "," + price;

       __doPostBack('<%=UpdatePanel2.ClientID %>', 'addTocart');
    }
```

And as you can see we can pass parameters to the control or just write NULL.
And i place the control in the update panel like this....

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">

    </asp:ScriptManager> 

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
               <ContentTemplate>
                   <uc1:Basket ID="Basket1" runat="server"  />  
             </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

This works absolutely perfect for me i don't know if there is any drawback using this concept.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a page WebMethod or a WebService to load the html from the ascx and serve it to your javascript.  There's a tutorial [here](http://encosia.com/boost-aspnet-performance-with-deferred-content-loading/) for doing it.